# emacs ivy: disable ido completition

Tags: ido, ivy

I am using GNU Emacs 26.2 and ivy from melpa.

When I run `M-x` and enter:
`M-x magit-status`

ivy suggests:

```
ido-enter-magit-status
magit-status
magit-status-mode
```

I don't use use `ido`, I have no idea that GNU Emacs includes, before I started use `ivy`. Any way to remove any `ido-` interactive functions from suggestion list?

Comment: in fact `ido-enter-magit-status` is defined by magit itself (in `magit-extras.el`).

Comment: `ido` ships with Emacs, so you shouldn't remove it. I don't know whether `ivy` provides any way to filter out certain completions, but that would be my first thing to look for in order to try to solve this problem.